# Pushing to a JavaScript array via key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object formatted as follows;

```
$scope.data = [
    {
        key: "Control",
        values: [ ]
    },
    {
        key: "Experiment",
        values: [ ]
    }
];
```

I simply want to be able to push to either one of these arrays by giving their key value.

I've tried;

```
$scope.data.keys("Experiment").values.push(thing);
```

But I get undefined. 
Sure this isn't very hard but I'm having trouble finding an answer on here or via the JS documentation

The reason I'm doing it in this way is because the JS library I'm using expects the data in a specific way

Comment: i think the push will work, the keys('experiment') looks like the problem

Comment: You really overcomplicate things. Instead of an array of objects with `key` and `value` just use an object.

Comment: @tkausl said, use `{ control: [], experiment: [] }` this will allow you to access the values: `data.experiment.push(thing)`

Comment: The reason I'm doing it in this way is because the JS library I'm using expects the data in a specific way

Comment: You cannot use a simple object and then later *transform* it into the needed structure...?

Comment: Thats probably a better way to approach it actually. I'll try it and see how it goes

Comment: @LeIshMan My answer below takes this approach if you need some example code.

Comment: I added the following suggestion to my answer: `$scope.data = { "Control": [],  "Experiment": []}`

use it liek `$scope.data["Experiment"].push("thing")` - if you can restructure you data please do it in this way :)

Answer (score 2):

Not very efficiant but short:

```
$scope.data.filter(function(v){return v.key == "Experiment"})[0].values.push(thing)
```

A fast way to do it:

```
for (var i = $scope.data.length; i--;) {
  if ($scope.data[i].key == "Experiment") {
    $scope.data[i].values.push("one more thing")
    break
  }
}
```

## How you should have done it:

```
$scope.data = {
  "Control": [],
  "Experiment": []
}

$scope.data["Experiment"].push("thing")
```

Demo:

```js
var $scope = {}
$scope.data = [{
  key: "Control",
  values: []
}, {
  key: "Experiment",
  values: []
}];

// Short
$scope.data.filter(function(v) {
  return v.key == "Experiment"
})[0].values.push("thing")

// Fast
for (var i = $scope.data.length; i--;) {
  if ($scope.data[i].key == "Experiment") {
    $scope.data[i].values.push("one more thing")
    break
  }
}

// Output for the Demo
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify($scope.data, null, "\t") + "</pre>")

// !!! What you should do:
$scope.data = {
  "Control": [],
  "Experiment": []
}

$scope.data["Experiment"].push("thing")
// Output for the Demo
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify($scope.data, null, "\t") + "</pre>")
```

Comment: because you iterate **all** over.

Comment: @NinaScholz and the others don't? Event that is no reason to downvote anybody here.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the structure, you can use `Array#some` (ES5) or `Array#find` (ES2015), both of which can be shimmed/polyfilled on older browsers.

`Array#some`:

```
$scope.data.some(function(entry) {
    if (entry.key == "Experiment") {
        entry.values.push(thing);
        return true;
    }
});
```

`Array#find`:

```
$scope.data.find(function(entry) { return entry.key == "Experiment"}).values.push(thing);
```

`Array#find` with ES2015's arrow functions:

```
$scope.data.find(entry => entry.key == "Experiment").values.push(thing);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `map` function to do this :

```
$scope.data.map(function(v){
    if(v.key=='Experiment') {
        v.values.push(thing);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create it as an object instead of an array and then convert it into an array when you need to pass it to the JS library.

```
$scope.data = { 
    "Control" : [ ],
    "Experiment" : [ ]
}

// Convert to array
var converted = [];
for (var key in $scope.data) {
    if ($scope.data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        converted.push({ key: key, values: $scope.data[key] });
    }
}

// Or using map
var converted = Object.keys($scope.data).map(function(key) { 
    return { key: key, values: $scope.data[key] };
});
```

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evcfthch/)

Answer (score -1):

here is the protocol which will work fine. I have removed $scope for the testing

```js
Array.prototype.addElement = function(key, value){
 for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
      if(this[i]['key'] == key){
       this[i]['values'].push(value);
      }
  }
}

var data = [
    {
        key: "Control",
        values: [ ]
    },
    {
        key: "Experiment",
        values: [ ]
    }
];
data.addElement("Control", "values");
data.addElement("Control", "values1");
data.addElement("Control", "values2");
data.addElement("Experiment", "values3");
console.log(data);
```

Comment: @NinaScholz stop downvoting all posts just because you have a bad day.

Comment: Prototype is the bast way for JavaScript to manage such complex array structure.

Comment: @NinaScholz if you think there is possible short circuit then give ans.

Comment: you could return after pushing the value.

Comment: @NinaScholz Please test and then comment no need to return value